# Forçar o PostgreSQL a utilizar um índice, há como?

Tags: postgresql, índices

Existe um forma de forçar o PostgreSQL a utilizar um índice específico?

Possuo duas tabelas iguais (servidores diferentes, é claro), com os mesmos indices criados em cada uma, porém, em um servidor o índice é utilizado e no outro não.

Preciso fazer com que pegue o índice, o `SELECT` é simples, tem apenas um `JOIN` porém a tabela muito grande, preciso desse índice.

Comment: Rode um ANALYZE nas duas máquinas para atualizar as estatísticas e refaça seu teste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez não tenha nada errado, o volume de dados nessas tabelas pode ser o responsável por esse comportamento.

Pense assim:

Imagine um livro com `5000` páginas. A melhor maneira de se encontrar algo específico dentro desse livro, certamente seria usando seu índice.

Agora imagine uma livreto de apenas `6` páginas. A maneira mais fácil de se encontrar algo dentro desse livreto seria folheando-o do começo ao fim, a necessidade de um índice é completamente desnecessária e poderia até mesmo atrapalhar.

Mas se você quiser se aventurar em forçar o `Postgres` a trabalhar dando preferência aos índices, voce pode fazer algo como:

```
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;
```

Comment: @L.Gustavo: Inclua mais detalhes na sua pergunta que eu complemento a resposta.

Comment: Criei os índices em um dia, no dia seguinte o banco começou a utilizar.